# Phonegap multiple file read

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm looking for reading multiple files in an Android device file system with Phonegap, so then, in just one multipart POST request, I can submit it to the server.

My problem is that I don´t want to store the firsts files read, so when the last file finish loading, I can submit all of them in one server call.

Below, taken from Phonegap docs, is an example of reading just one file.

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Does exist some way to sync the **gotFile** callback so that I have all the files in memory when I want to POST them?

If not, is it ok if I store the binary files in browser memory taking in care the amount of memory they occup? Or show I use LocalStorage?

Thanks!

Comment: if they won't fit in RAM, there's no way they would fit in localStorage, which is only a few megs. if you want to send them in one POST, they will need to be in RAM all at once. If that's too much, then you can post them one at a time and not call reader.readAsXXX() until the previous file's upload POST completes.

Comment: Images will be photos taken with an Android device, I suppose that I can more or less control their size. However, I can't make multiple requests because the images upload must be transactional and I can't chnage server code. Thanks!

Comment: Assume that I can store images in memory. Can I sync the gotFile callbacks? Is more a Javascript or programming question..

Comment: you can make an empty array, convert the list of files to an array and pop() file entries, then push into the empty array in the reader callback. When the output array's length is the same as the file list's length (the orig not the now-empty array), upload your whole array of dataURLs in one POST. not sure the exact mechanism your server needs to do that, but that's how the JS side could work...